# How can I implement a conditional panel revealed by clicking an arrowhead?

Tags: r, shiny

This is mostly about aesthetics. I can implement such optional panel using a check-box, e.g.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("show_panel", "advanced settings"),
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.show_panel == true",
    p("Some advanced settings here.")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works well, but I would like `checkboxInput` to be an arrowhead pointing right, then pointing down when clicked. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you rather use a droprown from the **shinyWidgets** package?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know them. `dropdownButton()` is close, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility using a custom click handler. It checks whether the icon (`icon("angle-right")`) is clicked and if so, it is replaced by `icon("angle-down")`. Also, `show_panel` is set to `true` in this case such that the `conditionalPanel` expands. The same happens vice versa if the `conditionalPanel` is opened when clicking the icon.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function() {

    var j = 1;

    $('#icon').on('click', function() {
        j = j + 1;
        if (j % 2 === 0) {
            Shiny.setInputValue('show_panel', true);
            $('#icon')[0].innerHTML = $('#icon')[0].innerHTML.replaceAll('-right', '-down');
        } else {
            Shiny.setInputValue('show_panel', false);
            $('#icon')[0].innerHTML = $('#icon')[0].innerHTML.replaceAll('-down', '-right');
        }
    });

    $('#icon').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });

});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    
    h4(div(id = "icon", icon("angle-right", style = "color: blue;"),
       "advanced settings")),
    
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.show_panel === true",
                     p("Some advanced settings here."))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What if I want a second dropdown panel though? I see it's this `show_panel` variable, but I wouldn't know how to define it outside the chunk of code...

Comment: You would create a second panel by using `conditionalPanel` and set a condition, say, such as `input.show_second_panel === true`. You may also need a second icon (`id = icon2`) and then you can adapt the code inside `js` to the new variables. Does this answer the question?